# ¿El this en una clase de Javascript es para los constructores?

Tags: javascript

Siempre uso:

```
function Constructor() {
    this.algo = algo;
}
```

Pero realmente, ¿Para qué uso el `this`? Sólo lo uso porque entiendo que esa propiedad, al colocarse el 'this', estará diciendo que la *propiedad* es para ese *constructor*. ¿Es así?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En javascript la palabra reservada u operador [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this) hace referencia al objeto actual, puedo puede ser modificada (ver uso de [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind)) para otros propósitos.

Sirve, por norma general, para diferenciar entre variables de ámbito global y local, accediendo a la del objeto.

Te pongo un ejemplo para mostrarte la diferencia.

```js
var variable = 'Esta es una variable global';
var objeto = {
  variable: 'Esta es una variable de objeto',
  prueba: 'Esto no debería funcionar sin "this"',
  Constructor: function() {
    var variable = 'Esta es una variable local';
    /* Primera ronda de pruebas */
    console.log('window.variable: ' + window.variable);
    console.log('this.variable: ' + this.variable);
    console.log('variable: ' + variable);
    /* Segunda ronda de pruebas */
    try {
      console.log('prueba: ' + prueba);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
    console.log('this.prueba: ' + this.prueba);
  }
};
objeto.Constructor();
```

Como podrás haber comprobado en la primera ronda de pruebas, las variables globales se definen en el ámbito de [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), las locales se acceden de forma directa y en el caso de las del ámbito del objeto debe usarse `this` para acceder a ellas.

En la segunda ronda de pruebas se genera una excepción `prueba is not defined` cuando intentamos acceder a una variable del objeto sin usar `this`.

Dependiendo del modo estricto o no y de varios ámbitos su comportamiento es diferente, pero por norma general su uso está ampliamente extendido en el ámbito de un objeto, pero en el *contexto global*, fuera de cualquier función, `this` se refiere al objeto global (ya sea en modo estricto o no).

Comment: muy bien explicado, gracias.

Comment: De nada, un placer. Si te queda alguna duda házmelo saber y trato de ampliar la respuesta con un nuevo ejemplo para aclararla.

Comment: gracias OscarGarcia, aunque mis dudas parezcan algo simples para algunos, para mi que recien aprendo es algo complicado, ya que estoy aprendiendo solo digitalmente, se agradece tu tiempo

Answer (score 2):

Básicamente porque en POO la palabra reservada *this* que generalmente se utiliza en Java, JavasScript, php (que tienen una sintaxis que por cierto es muy parecida entre ellas) hace referencia a la misma clase y su atributo en tu caso. Es como si la clase se llamara a sí misma y se trajera el atributo o el método.

Ahora por que en el constructor desde mi punto de vista sería porque si el constructor espera un parámetro y este se llama igual a un atributo de la clase no confunda qué variable se está llamando.

Te lo demuestro con PHP:

```
Class Humano{
    private nombre;
    function __contruct__(nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre
    }
}
```

La clase *Humano* tiene un atributo llamado *nombre* y en el constructor se espera un parámetro llamado *nombre*. En este punto entra en juego el *this*. Entonces con el *this* se está llamando al atributo de la clase, mas no al atributo que espera el constructor.

Comment: Aclarar que no es requisito que el constructor reciba parametros. El metodo constructor es el que se llama nada mas crear un objeto de esa clase, por lo que, si esa clase necesita inicializar parametros, este es el metodo para ello.

Comment: Furioso: intenta repasar el redactado. Es algo confuso y es una pena para una publicación tan útil.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso en particular no es necesario el this. En cualquier asignacion de un atributo de clase si no se escribe la palabra this el compilador la entendera de todas formas, es decir por default el compilador le antecederá el this a cualquier asignación de forma implícita. En este caso el uso de this es simplemente una buena practica para que el programa sea mas legible a nivel humano y el programador no tenga que "pensar" como un compilador.
De hecho si probaras escribir en el constructor algo = algo verias que el resultado es el mismo pero es menos amigable a los ojos.

Answer (score 0):

En JavaScript usamos **this** como un shortcut como referencia a un objecto;

```
var Person = {
  name: 'Bill',
  lastname: 'Gates',
  getFullName: function () {
    return this.name + ' ' + this.lastname
  },
};
```

**this** es algo que el intérprete JavaScript mantiene mientras evalúa el código JavaScript, como un registro de CPU especial que contiene una referencia a un objeto.

Es muy util cuando creas clases ya sea usando prototypes o class

```
class Person {
  constructor() {
    super(); // super help us to call functions on an object's parent.
    this.name = 'Bill';
    this.lastname = 'Gates'
  }

  getFullName() {
    return this.name + ' ' + this.lastname;
  }
}
```